# Transferring/emailing files created by Quarto

Tags: r, sendmailr, quarto

When I would create a html document in RMarkdown, the file transfer/email process was straightforward; I would simply transfer/email the resulting html file.

However, when I try to do the same with a Quarto document, I do not get all of the functionality in the transferred file.  For example, my Quarto document includes tabs using the `::: {.panel-tabset}` option.  When I open the transferred html document, the panel-tabsets are not displayed properly.

I believe that this is because Quarto also produces files in a separate directory. However, I trying to programmatically email the html document out to a distribution, and sendmailR is not letting me attach this directory.

Furthermore, my distribution list are NOT technical folks.  I am not looking to have to tell them to save these files and then open the html; I was hoping to just attach the html file like I did with RMarkdown and have them natively open it just like an regular attachment.

What is the best way to transfer/email Quarto produced html documents?

Comment: Can you provide code for both `quarto` and `sendmailR` that you are using and also the directory information of yours. Because as my experience quarto produces the output where the source document is.

Answer (score 5):

Someone directed me to use the html:  self-contained in the YAML header.
Based on that, I found [this post](https://quarto.org/docs/output-formats/html-basics.html#self-contained) which states what to do.

By putting the following in my YAML header, the resultant html file is self-contained:

```
---
format:
  html:
    self-contained: true
---
```